# Parsing nested JSON into a list of Tuples with Aeson

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

Say I have the following structure:

```
data AddressDto = AddressDto
  { addressDtoId                   :: UUID 
  , addressDtoCode                 :: Text
  , addressDtoCity                 :: Maybe Text 
  , addressDtoStreet               :: Text 
  , addressDtoPostCode             :: Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON AddressDto where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON $ apiOptions "addressDto"

instance ToJSON AddressDto where
  toJSON = genericToJSON $ apiOptions "addressDto"
  toEncoding = genericToEncoding $ apiOptions "addressDto"
```

This works as you would expect.

Now say I want to parse a JSON structure of the format:

```
{ UUID: AddressDto, UUID: AddressDto, UUID: AddressDto }
```

A reasonable Haskell representation would seem to be:

```
data AddressListDto = AddressListDto [(UUID, AddressDto)]
```

Creating a helper function like so:

```
keyAndValueToList :: Either ServiceError AddressListDto -> Text -> DiscountDto -> Either ServiceError AddressListDto
keyAndValueToList (Left err) _ _ = Left err
keyAndValueToList (Right (AddressListDto ald)) k v = do
  let maybeUUID = fromString $ toS k 
  case maybeUUID of 
    Nothing        -> Left $ ParseError $ InvalidDiscountId k
    Just validUUID -> Right $ AddressListDto $ (validUUID, v) : ald
```

and finally an instance of FromJSON:

```
instance FromJSON AddressListDto where
  parseJSON = withObject "tuple" $ \o -> do 
    let result = foldlWithKey' keyAndValueToList (Right $ AddressListDto []) o
    case result of
      Right res -> pure res
      Left err -> throwError err
```

This fails to compile with:

```
Couldn't match type ‘aeson-1.4.5.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value’
                     with ‘AddressDto’
      Expected type: unordered-containers-0.2.10.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                       Text AddressDto
```

Two questions:

1) How do I make sure the nested values in the hashmap get parsed correctly to an AddressDto.
2) How do I avoid forcing the initial value into an either? Is there a function I could use instead of `foldlWithKey'` that didn't make me wrap the initial value like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny answer. To implement `parseJSON`, you can use

```
parseJSON :: Value -> Parser (HashMap Text AddressDto)
```

...but even better, why not just use a type alias instead of a fresh data type, so:

```
type AddressListDto = HashMap UUID AddressDto
```

This already has a suitable `FromJSON` instance, so then you don't even need to write any code yourself.